# Getting all column values that match even though value is slighty different

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, table A and Table B each with 4 columns. Table A has a column `model` value = 'civic' and table B has column `modelname` value of 'civic sedan'.

I want to select all the rows in table A where table A.model = B.modelname even though table B.modelname is a little different but still contains 'civic' in this example.

```
select A.model as modelname, B.jpgname
from A, B
where A.year = B.year
and A.year = '2016'
and A.make = B.make
and A.make = 'honda'
and A.model LIKE B.modelname
group by model
```

That code gets all the other honda models except for example, the 'civic sedan' in table B.

I am probably missing something really simple. Thanks for any help!

Comment: and A.model  like concat(B.modelName,'%')

Comment: `and B.modelname LIKE CONCAT('%',A.Model,'%')`

Comment: or even more robust: `and (B.modelname LIKE CONCAT('%',A.Model,'%') OR A.Model LIKE CONCAT('%',B.Modename,'%') )` in case the longer string is in `A.Model`

Comment: Thanks, the concat worked perfect. The string will always be longer in the B table but that's good solution if A.model is longer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `concat` , like this:

```
select A.model as modelname, B.jpgname
from A, B
where A.year = B.year
and A.year = '2016'
and A.make = B.make
and A.make = 'honda'
and B.modelname LIKE concat('%',A.model,'%')
group by model
```